# No keyboard on Cordova + Marionette project using ionic Keboard plugin

Tags: cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework

Don't know if it makes sense to use ionic keyboard plugin on Cordova project, I added it to my cordova IOS project and in my view rendering I called "cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show()" and this is what I got (no keyboard only AccessoryBar) http://grab.by/BFX6 frowning

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my question, the Keyboard pop up automatically on IOS without plugins, I tested it with phonegap dev app and it works just fine :)